# Choosing of root in proving $\mathrm{Arccos} z = -i \mathrm{Ln}(z + \sqrt{z^2-1})$

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove: $$\mathrm{Arccos} z = -i \mathrm{Ln}(z + \sqrt{z^2-1})$$
Where $z \in \mathbb C$

#### My Problem:

When I set $$z = \cos t = \frac{1}{2}(e^{it} + e^{-it})$$
I got $$(e^{it})^2 - 2z \cdot e^{it} + 1 =0$$
And I should get double roots:
$$e^{it} = z \pm \sqrt{z^2-1}$$

However, in what we are trying to prove, there is only one root appearing.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In complex analysis, $\sqrt{}$ is a multi-valued function (since it is defined via Log, which is multi-valued), so in the Arccos formula you are trying to prove, there actually are two roots appearing. The formula
$$
\text{Arccos }z = -i\cdot \text{Ln }(z\pm\sqrt{1-z^2})
$$
is equally correct, but the $\pm$ is redundant, since it is already implied the use of $\sqrt{}$.

Answer (score 1):

As $(z)^2-(\sqrt{z^2-1})^2=1$

if $z\pm\sqrt{z^2-1}=e^{it}, z\mp\sqrt{z^2-1}=e^{-it}$

Adding we get $2z=e^{it}+e^{-it}=2\cos t\iff x=\cos t\implies t=\arccos(z)$

So, both branches are legitimate as corroborated [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Example_proof) and [here](https://www.math.washington.edu/~marshall/math_427/arccos.html)